# Jenkins EC2 plugin: instances not starting

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, jenkins-plugins

This is my Jenkins EC2 configuration:

- URL: **$JENKINS_URL/configureClouds/**
- Add new cloud: **Amazon EC2**
- Name: **Amazon EC2 eu-central-1**
- Amazon EC2 Credentials: **AKIA...**
- Region: **eu-central-1**
- EC2 Key Pair's Private Key: **ubuntu**
- Test connection: **success**
- Advanced...
- Instance Cap: **3**
- No delay provisioning: **checked**
- Add AMI
- Description: **Linux node**
- AMI ID: **ami-0293...**
- Check AMI: **05052029...**
- Instance Type: **T3aMedium**
- EBS Optimized: **checked**
- Monitoring: **checked**
- T2 Unlimited: **checked**
- Security group names: **sg-0c2d...** (opens SSH port 22)
- Remote FS root: **./jenkins**
- Remote user: **ubuntu**
- AMI Type: **unix**
- Labels: **aws ubuntu linux**
- Usage: **Use this node as much as possible**
- Idle termination time: **30**
- Advanced...
- Number of executors: **2**
- Stop/Disconnect on Idle Timeout: **checked**
- Minimum number of instances: **1**
- Minimum number of spare instances: **0**
- Instance cap: **10**
- Block device mapping: **/dev/sda1=snap-0eadbe3f...:200:true:gp2, /dev/sdb=ephemeral0, /dev/sdc=ephemeral1**
- Associate Public IP: **checked**
- Connection Strategy: **Public DNS**
- Host Key Verification Strategy: **off**
- Maximum Total Uses: **10**
- Environment variables: **checked**
  (not listing all environment variables)
- Tool locations: **checked**
  (not listing all tool locations)

With this configuration, I would expect that at least 1 EC2 instance would be started, but no instance is started.

In the nodes page in Jenkins when I hit the provision via  button, I get an error:

> Oops! A problem occurred while processing the request. Logging ID=8ead3651-3809-4a47-984c-e0e494c705bb

In /log/all I have:

```
Apr 14, 2021 5:34:37 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate getImage
Getting image for request {ExecutableUsers: [],Filters: [],ImageIds: [ami-0293c4ed***],Owners: []}
Apr 14, 2021 5:34:37 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate logProvisionInfo
SlaveTemplate{description='Linux node', labels='aws ubuntu linux'}. Considering launching
Apr 14, 2021 5:34:37 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate setupRootDevice
AMI had /dev/sda1
Apr 14, 2021 5:34:37 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate setupRootDevice
{DeleteOnTermination: true,SnapshotId: snap-0eadbe3f***,VolumeSize: 20,VolumeType: gp2,Encrypted: false}
Apr 14, 2021 5:34:37 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate logProvisionInfo
SlaveTemplate{description='Linux node', labels='aws ubuntu linux'}. Setting Instance Initiated Shutdown Behavior : ShutdownBehavior.Stop
Apr 14, 2021 5:34:37 PM INFO hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate logProvisionInfo
SlaveTemplate{description='Linux node', labels='aws ubuntu linux'}. Looking for existing instances with describe-instance: {Filters: [{Name: image-id,Values: [ami-0293c4ed***]}, {Name: instance-type,Values: [t3a.medium]}, {Name: key-name,Values: [***]}, {Name: tag:jenkins_server_url,Values: [https://jenkins.***.com/]}, {Name: tag:jenkins_slave_type,Values: [demand_Linux node]}],InstanceIds: [],}
Apr 14, 2021 5:34:37 PM WARNING hudson.init.impl.InstallUncaughtExceptionHandler handleException
Caught unhandled exception with ID c080ae42-6b7b-47aa-93ea-1b8064503c1c
com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.AmazonEC2Exception: Value () for parameter groupId is invalid. The value cannot be empty (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue; Request ID: da74dbbf-0685-45ac-8454-c3f5d1b4c700; Proxy: null)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1819)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleServiceErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1403)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1372)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1145)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:802)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:704)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:550)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:530)
    at com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2Client.doInvoke(AmazonEC2Client.java:29240)
    at com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2Client.invoke(AmazonEC2Client.java:29207)
    at com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2Client.invoke(AmazonEC2Client.java:29196)
    at com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2Client.executeRunInstances(AmazonEC2Client.java:28011)
    at com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2Client.runInstances(AmazonEC2Client.java:27980)
    at hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate.provisionOndemand(SlaveTemplate.java:1100)
    at hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate.provisionOndemand(SlaveTemplate.java:1042)
    at hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate.provision(SlaveTemplate.java:867)
    at hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud.getNewOrExistingAvailableSlave(EC2Cloud.java:693)
    at hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2Cloud.doProvision(EC2Cloud.java:430)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:627)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:396)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:408)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.interceptor.RequirePOST$Processor.invoke(RequirePOST.java:77)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.PreInvokeInterceptedFunction.invoke(PreInvokeInterceptedFunction.java:26)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:212)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:145)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$11.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:536)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:766)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:898)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$4.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:281)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:766)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:898)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:694)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:240)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:791)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ssegateway.Endpoint$SSEListenChannelFilter.doFilter(Endpoint.java:248)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at jenkins.security.ResourceDomainFilter.doFilter(ResourceDomainFilter.java:76)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at jenkins.telemetry.impl.UserLanguages$AcceptLanguageFilter.doFilter(UserLanguages.java:129)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at hudson.plugins.audit_trail.AuditTrailFilter.doFilter(AuditTrailFilter.java:111)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at io.jenkins.blueocean.auth.jwt.impl.JwtAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:60)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.support.slowrequest.SlowRequestFilter.doFilter(SlowRequestFilter.java:37)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at io.jenkins.blueocean.ResourceCacheControl.doFilter(ResourceCacheControl.java:134)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.modernstatus.ModernStatusFilter.doFilter(ModernStatusFilter.java:50)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at hudson.plugins.greenballs.GreenBallFilter.doFilter(GreenBallFilter.java:64)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at jenkins.metrics.impl.MetricsFilter.doFilter(MetricsFilter.java:125)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:92)
    at jenkins.security.AcegiSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(AcegiSecurityExceptionFilter.java:52)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:97)
    at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:105)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:92)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:218)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:97)
    at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:62)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:97)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:109)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at jenkins.security.SuspiciousRequestFilter.doFilter(SuspiciousRequestFilter.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:578)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1435)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1350)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:633)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:882)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1036)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: What does the instance log in Jenkins say when you try to start an instance? Does it have the iam permissions required to start an instance

Comment: @apr_1985 there can only be an instance log when an instance starts. I don't even get that far. Also, and I don't know if you know this, with the EC2 plugin you cannot "just" start an instance. The plugin automatically creates and destroys instances, and when there is zero load on Jenkins, then the instances do not exist at all. However I have configured to have at least one instance online at all times, and even that one isn't created.

Comment: And it's the root user so it definitely has permissions. Bad practice, I know, but as long as IT doesn't tell me to do it otherwise, then it just works.

Comment: I meant in the nodes page in Jenkins when you hit the provision via <cloud Name> button what errors are you seeing (rather than the AWS instance log).  Also root user is that an AWS admin user as that is shocking practice :D

Comment: I get *"Oops!
A problem occurred while processing the request.
Logging ID=8ead3651-3809-4a47-984c-e0e494c705bb"*

Comment: If you search your main Jenkins log for that ID you should see the stack trace from the AWS SDK API which may give some indication as to what went wrong. (might have to generate another error as the log may have rotated that error away)
<jenkins URL>/log/all

Comment: @apr_1985 I have edited my answer to add the error log.

Comment: From this https://issues.jenkins.io/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/JENKINS-39960 I would guess that either your security group or the subnet your are launching into is incorrect?

Comment: Thank youI It was indeed a missing subnet. After that I got another error about device mapping, but this time I knew where to find the error log and I could fix that myself. Once that was done, an instance was immediately starting up. I can't connect to it yet, but that's a different error, and I am going to replace my ed25519 with a rsa key because apparently the SSH key for starting the instance needs to be the same as for Jenkins connecting to the instance once it's started, and AWS does not support ed25519.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write up of the comments for anyone else looking for help diagnosing EC2 Agent Plugin issue.

- When you have configured your agents go to the Nodes page (Jenkins URL/computer)
- Hit the button to Provision a new agent from your cloud
- If there is a configuration issue you will get Evil Jenkins and a Logging ID
- Go to Jenkins logs page (Jenkins URL/log/all) and search that ID
- This should give you the stack trace from the AWS SDK call which will help you to narrow down whether is it missing config or IAM permissions etc at fault

If there were no config errors you would get taken to the node that is being launched config page where you would be able to see its EC2 startup log to check for any User Data or AMI issues.

Comment: I got the error "No such template". Any idea what I need to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

For this particular issue 'Value () for parameter groupId is invalid' the plugin is expecting you to provide a list or at least one subnet-id in configuration.

I faced the same issue and was resolved with this.